# to consume POST request client method using WEBCLIENT

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, client, webclient

I'm new to the WebClient field, but I'm running into the following problem. This is my client method, which you have seen should insert the values that I have sent to the parameter to the database, but I cannot insert it.

```
 @Override
    public Mono<BulkSmsRequestResource> sendSms(BulkSmsRequestResource request) {
        Mono<BulkSmsRequestResource> bulkSmsRequestResourceMono = webClientBuilder.build()
                .post()
                .uri(url1)
                .body(Mono.just(request), BulkSmsRequestResource.class)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(BulkSmsRequestResource.class);
        return bulkSmsRequestResourceMono;

    }
```

The code I wrote here is my controller area.

```
@PostMapping("/send")
public ResponseEntity<? extends ResponseResource> sendSms(@RequestBody BulkSmsRequestResource request) {
    if (request == null) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(
                new ErrorResponseResource(
                        "Transaction failed successfully!",
                        400),
                HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
    this.smsSendService.sendSms(request);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(new SuccessResponseResource("Transaction done successfully", 200), HttpStatus.OK);

}
```

When I run my method, I can't add the values to the database on the server side, but I can get the values from there using the following method using the client method.

```
@Override
public Flux<BulkSmsResponseDto> findAll() {
    Flux<BulkSmsResponseDto> bulkSmsResponseDtoFlux = webClientBuilder.build()
            .get()
            .uri(url2)
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToFlux(BulkSmsResponseDto.class);
    return bulkSmsResponseDtoFlux;
}
```

Comment: How are you making the effective call to `sendSms`?

Comment: What do you mean, I can't understand.

Comment: Where exactly (and how) in your code you are making the call to the resource creation method `public Mono<BulkSmsRequestResource> sendSms(BulkSmsRequestResource request)`? Can you add the whole relevant code?

Comment: As you can see, I create it at the service layer, and only call it at the controller layer.

Comment: Just wanted to make sure as you did not refer to how the `findAll` method was called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to trigger the `WebClient` reactive request, you must subscribe to the lattery to trigger the HTTP call:

```
service.sendSms(request)
    .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

Otherwise, you will have to chain the `Mono<?>` to the controller method result so that the underlying infrastructure (*Spring* in this case) will know how to handle it (subscribing to it at alter point resulting in the HTTP call being invoked).

So in order to have the `WebClient` request triggered upon your controller endpoint invocation, you have to map its return result to the proper `ResponseEntity` then return the result `Mono`:

```
@PostMapping("/send")
public Mono<ResponseEntity<? extends ResponseResource>> sendSms(@RequestBody BulkSmsRequestResource request) {
    if (request == null) {
        return Mono.just(new ResponseEntity<>(
                new ErrorResponseResource(
                        "Transaction failed successfully!",
                        400),
                HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST));
    }
    return this.smsSendService.sendSms(request)
        .map(result -> new ResponseEntity<>(new SuccessResponseResource("Transaction done successfully", 200), HttpStatus.OK));
}
```

***Design side note:** Maybe you need to update the response with proper HTTP code (201) along with a reference to the created resource.*

Comment: Great Answer, much thanks. I need to learn the WebClient library urgently, but as you can see, I couldn't find anything good. Do you know any place?

Comment: The official documentation should be the place to go for a starter, I couldn’t think of any better resource :)